# Alter Regex to validate email Domain on RFC 5322 from Java to Oracle sql

Tags: javascript, regex, oracle, email

I need to alter the *below Regex* to validate emails domains in a oracle database, according to RFC 5322, 
and ensuring that the criteria below are respected as well.

Domain rules that must be respected:

1. must start an end with a letter or digit and be between 1 and 63 characters long.
2. may contain uppercase and lowercase Latin letters (A to Z and a to z).
3. may contain digits 0 to 9, provided that top-level domain names are not all-numeric.
4. may contain hyphen -, provided that it is not the first or last character, and not consecutive also.
5. must have at least 2 or more characters (abc@t.com is not valid, but abc@tt.com is valid).

I found on the internet the regex below, that works very well and ensure the rules posted above, in Javascript.
My problem is that ORACLE does not support look-ahead/-behind.

```
@(?:(?=[A-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.)[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)*\.){1,8}[A-Z]{2,63}$
```

So, can anyone please help me on making the necessary modifications in order to work in Oracle sql?

Comment: For point 5 you might use `(?:[A-Z0-9]+-)*[A-Z0-9]{2,}\.[A-Z0-9]{2,63}$` https://regex101.com/r/3dut5y/1 Not sure if it is possible to get the max of 63 chars with the quantifiers and the hyphen in between without a lookahead.

Comment: Your current regex is _not_ matching conditions 2 through 5, because it doesn't even allow for an `@` symbol, which is a critical part of the email.  Please include a working email regex with lookaheads.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvinience; The regex was looking only for domain part excluding the '@'. I've made the proper correction. Thank you

Comment: @LEOPOLDO Maybe it defeats the purpose of using a regex only, but perhaps you can split the string on `@` and count the number of chars using code and validate the second part using the pattern above for point nr. 5

Comment: yes. Validates point 5, but validates emails with just one domain like 'test@test.com'; but fails on emails with more than one like 'test@test.com.pt'. Thank you in advance

Comment: Bit of a tangent, but have you considered handing the validation off to a Java stored procedure?

Comment: In my work I only have possibility to work with oracle. I'm using TOAD interface too.

Comment: Java stored procedures [are within the Oracle database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdev/running-Java-stored-procedures.html#GUID-11B2344A-7C07-4DFB-90D1-748EA814F5E6). Just an idea though *8-)

Comment: Thank you Alex for your information. I'm kind of rookie in database systems, not enough to understand the process. I'm starting my experince with oracle sql only 3 yars ago.