# ORACLE regex Match email Domain with two or more characters

Tags: regex, oracle11g

I need to be able to accept email Domains only with two or more characters, like shown below:

With my actual regex I'm validating domains with just one char, like a@b.com.

```
@([A-Z0-9]+(-[A-Z0-9]+)*\.){1,8}[A-Z]{2,63}$
```

Expected results:

```
"a@b.com" Not valid  (just one char after @)
"a@bb.com" Is Valid  (two chars after @)
"a@b-domain.com" Is valid  (two or more chars after @)
```

All I need is to made change my regex to permit domains that starts with at least 2 characters.

Thank you.

Comment: Try just `@[[:alnum:]][-[:alnum:]]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,63}$` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a suggestion in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60870491/alter-regex-to-validate-email-domain-on-rfc-5322-from-java-to-oracle-sql) for the last issue, you might use

```
@([A-Z0-9]+-)*[A-Z0-9]{2,}\.[A-Z0-9]{2,63}$
```

- `@` Match literally
- `([A-Z0-9]+-)*` 0+ repetitions of 1+ chars A-Z0-9 followed by `-`
- `[A-Z0-9]{2,}` Match 2 or more times A-Z0-9
- `\.[A-Z0-9]{2,63}` Match a dot and 2-63 times A-Z0-9
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UCaoGT/1)

To allow a hyphen or an underscore you could use a character class:

```
@([A-Z0-9]+[_-])*[A-Z0-9]{2,}\.[A-Z0-9]{2,63}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J6KmkM/1)

Comment: Many thank's, it works. I've  just noticed that my regex does not consider '_' (underscores). If they are permited, and do they folow the same rule as hyphens, where can I insert in regex?

Comment: @LEOPOLDO In that case you could use a character class `@([A-Z0-9]+[_-])*[A-Z0-9]{2,}\.[A-Z0-9]{2,63}$` https://regex101.com/r/J6KmkM/1

Comment: Hi again. There's a problem that I only notice just now. @([A-Z0-9]+-)*[A-Z0-9]{2,}\.[A-Z0-9]{2,63}$ only accepts one dot '.' in all domain. Before it woul accept "abc@bbd.fff.com" with the two dots possibility. Can you help please?

Comment: @LEOPOLDO Yes of course, you could for example use a quantifier and a group to accept 1 or more `@([A-Z0-9]+[_-])*[A-Z0-9]{2,}(\.[A-Z0-9]{2,63})+$` https://regex101.com/r/IwqPVr/1 or use `@([A-Z0-9]+[_-])*[A-Z0-9]{2,}(\.[A-Z0-9]{2,63}){1,2}$` to accept 1 or 2 occurrences.

Comment: Many thank's once more. Forgive me, I'm kind of rookie. My original regex had the possibiliti to accept until 8 subdomains "{1,8}. Can you show me please how to alter both '@([A-Z0-9]+-)*[A-Z0-9]{2,}\.[A-Z0-9]{2,63}$' and '@([A-Z0-9]+[_-])*[A-Z0-9]{2,}\.[A-Z0-9]{2,63}$'. I'm so sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: You could combine them using `@([A-Z0-9]+[_-]){0,7}[A-Z0-9]{2,}(\.[A-Z0-9]{2,63})+$` https://regex101.com/r/maU2mE/1

Comment: I've tested and accepts more than 8 sub-domains. I've tried @(([A-Z0-9]+[_-]){0,7}[A-Z0-9]{2,}\.){1,8}[A-Z0-9]{2,63}$ seems not to work. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @LEOPOLDO Which subdomains are accepted and should not?

Comment: I don't have restrictions on specific subdomains. My only restriction is to the quantity. So this imaginary email should be validate. "abc@paris7.juieu.fr.gg.ggg.gg.ggg.gggg", But in case I need to specificate this four, for ex; 'gmail;hotmail;santander;totta', how could it be done, please?
I've tested your second sugestion and seems to work. '@([A-Z0-9]+[_-])*[A-Z0-9]{2,}(\.[A-Z0-9]{2,63}){1,8}$'. Thank you.